# Raising and lowing indices in Einstein notation -- First fundamental form under different parameterizations

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Surface S: $r(u^1, u^2)$ has an another parameterization $r(\tilde u^1, \tilde u^2)$ where $u^\alpha = u^\alpha(\tilde u^1, \tilde u^2)$, $\alpha = 1,2 $
Let $$a^\alpha_i = \frac{\partial u^\alpha}{\partial \tilde u^i}, \ \tilde a_\alpha^i = \frac{\partial \tilde u^i}{\partial u^\alpha}$$

$$g_{ij} = r_{u_i} \cdot r_{u_j}, \ \tilde g_{ij} = r_{\tilde u_i} \cdot r_{\tilde u_j}$$

$$(g^{ij})^{-1} = (g_{ij}), \ (\tilde g^{ij})^{-1} = (\tilde g_{ij}) \quad \text{(Matrix inverse)}$$

Show that $$\tilde g_{ij} = g_{\alpha \beta} a^\alpha_i a^\beta_j
,\ g^{\alpha \beta} = \tilde g^{ij}a^\alpha_i a^\beta_j$$

It's easy to prove the first equality. However, I'm having trouble dealing with the second. I have tried to use the first one to obtain a similar expression to the second, but didn't know how to raise the g indices to the other side.

Note: I'm new to the Einstein notation. Maybe there's some trick for raising and lowing indices. Please help.

Comment: I can't answer your question because I don't know about this subject, but the book Gravitation, by Misner, Wheeler and Thorne has a box named Index Gymnastics, with hints for raising and lowering indices. This may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's one approach. $g^{\alpha\beta}$ is uniquely determined by the equation $g^{\alpha\beta}g_{\beta\gamma} = \delta^\alpha_\gamma$. So you should just check that the right-hand-side will have this same property (using your first equality, of course): We want to show that
$$\tilde g^{ij}a_i^\alpha a_j^\beta g_{\beta\gamma} = \delta_\gamma^\alpha.$$
Think about multiplying this equation by the invertible matrix $[a_k^\gamma]$. Do we get the same result on each side?
Well:
\begin{gather*}
a_i^\alpha a_j^\beta g_{\beta\gamma} a_k^\gamma=a_i^\alpha\tilde g_{jk}, \quad\text {so}\\
\tilde g^{ij}a_i^\alpha a_j^\beta g_{\beta\gamma} a_k^\gamma = \tilde g^{ij} a_i^\alpha\tilde g_{jk} = a_i^\alpha \delta^i_k=a_k^\alpha = \delta^\alpha_\gamma a_k^\gamma,
\end{gather*} as required.

Comment: I haven't considered manipulating them  in terms of matrices before. Thanks!